# How to grant a VM access to a Resource Group in ARM?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I tried [Grant your VM access to a Resource Group in Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm#grant-your-vm-access-to-a-resource-group-in-azure-resource-manager)
 but it does not list any VM, althought I have plenty of VMs in my subscription:

```
No virtual machine managed identities found in this subscription
```

See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have not enabled the system-assigned managed identity for your VM, navigate to your VM in the portal -> `Identity` -> `System assigned` -> turn the `status` on, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#enable-system-assigned-managed-identity-on-an-existing-vm).

**Note**: Per my test, it seems to have some delay. If so, just use the filter with `Azure AD user, group, or service principal`, search your VM name, refer to the screenshot.

[image]